# How to count items in csv file python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm using kaggle imdb 5000 dataset you can see details [here](https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata). 
I'm trying to make new csv file look like [image: this].
But the genre row also has to split.

> Genre row:
>   [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]

How can I take name attributes in Genre row?

```
with open(filename) as myFile:  
    reader = csv.DictReader(myFile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['genres'].'name')
```

`print(row['genres'].'name')` doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you expect `r['genres'].'name'` to work, and *what do you expect it to do?*

Comment: That column contains JSON, as the page you linked mentions You should parse the JSON.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga actually, I don't expect it to work, I'm trying to get rid of all the data except movies' names, genres and overviews. But in genre column there is more info than just genres' names.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes Please don't solicit for checkmarks unless the asker has already indicated that your answer is correct (and you think they just don't know they're expected to). See [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer).

Comment: @glibdud As other users in the post you linked to state, it's perfectly fine to ask newer users to check the answers. Most newer users on SO unfortunately do not do so, suggesting they do so and leaving a friendly reminder is not demanding IMHO.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes But you'll notice that most suggest only doing it *after* your answer has already been acknowledged as helpful. Anyway, meta is the proper place to discuss. Just wanted to point it out.

Comment: @glibdud  - Thanks! will keep it in mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import json
with open(filename) as myFile:  
    reader = csv.DictReader(myFile)
    for row in reader:
        if not isinstance(row, dict):  # The row might be a string, in that case, parse it to a dict.
            row = json.loads(row)  # Parse the json row and convert it to dict.
        print([o['name'] for o in row])  # Iterate over every entry in the row and access the value 'name', will return a list of genre names.

        print(', '.join([o['name'] for o in row]))  # Will return a string of comma separated genre names.

        print([{'name': o['name']} for o in row])  # Will return a list of Genre objects, deleting all keys but 'name'
```

Comment: I tried to run your solution but I got an error says "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str." But I got your point where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Look more carefully to your own example:
you have a list of dictionaries with two keys : they are not nested.

```
{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}
```

`row['genres'].'name'` is wrong for the syntax and for what you are trying to do:

`row['genres']['name']` would mean: `{"id": { "name": "Action"} }`

So try take name attributes like:

```
print(row['genres'], row['name'])
```

for a neat example, see also the doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader